# What's the best way to check in a program whether the input string is a path?

Tags: string, scala, hadoop

I am writing a parser. In my system I either have a path (which is absolutely valid) or a name. I need to know that whether the current string entry is a path not the name. 
I want to use Hadoop.fs.Path and send a string to this class, I know that it will construct a path out of that string but what if the string is not a path? Do I need to write my own function to parse the path or is there any functionality available that I can use?

Thanks

Comment: And what is *a name*?

Comment: I might want to pass an operand or a number or having my own "if condition" those make that name part.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any string of reasonable length could be a path.  For instance, I might have a directory named `Richard` in the current directory, at which point `Richard` would be a valid path.  Also, the user could think there was such a path (but it's actually `Rich`) when it's missing.  So if you're asking, "How could I tell whether an arbitrary string is a path or not," the answer is *you can't*.

So in your parser you will have to go at it some other way.  Must the path exist?  If yes, just create the file object and ask if it exists (which you can do e.g. with `fs.FileSystem.exists` if you have a path object and are using Hadoop).  Alternatively, you need to decide on criteria for names (e.g. it exists in a database or map somewhere) and pick those out first, assuming everything else is a path.

Comment: thank you, that's a good idea assuming everything is a pass. I'll test it and hopefully it will work :)